# Is there a way in TypeORM query to use a function to fetch a value from a hashmap based on a key from the database field

Tags: typescript, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have a HashMap which contains empIDs and empCodes as follows:
`export const empIDCodeMap = new Map<number, number>([ [1, 100], [2, 156], [3, 160]])`

I have a query which needs to verify if the empCode matches based on the empID

For eg:

`this.query ("select * from employee e where e.empCode = (${empIDCodeMap.get(e.empID)})")`

This gives an error `"Cannot find name e"` .

Is there any way to get this TypeORM query to use the Map with the empId from the database row?

PS : This is just a simplified example but the sql used in the project is huge and this cannot be up modified to queryBuilder for now

Tried to use TypeORM query with a HashMap value fetch based on a database field Key.

Result : Error with cannot find name. Need to know if there is a way to do this